# C# : subreport of Crystal report not fetching data

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have an crystal report and I did add 2 subreport on it I fill main report with dataset 
with filling by dataadapter with a query such as this

```
string CTS = @"SELECT * FROM PPMPRT WHERE ID = '" + frm1.ID.Text + "'";
SCM.Parameters.Clear();
            SDA.SelectCommand = SCM;
            SDA.SelectCommand.CommandText = CTS;
            SDA.SelectCommand.Connection = SCO;
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            if (SCO.State != ConnectionState.Open) SCO.Open();
            SDA.Fill(DT);
            ReportDocument RD = new ReportDocument();
            RD.Load("rptPPM.rpt");
            RD.SetDataSource(DT);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RD;
            crystalReportViewer1.Show();
```

My subreports don't show any data I also linked them within main report on design.

How can I do now?

Comment: I think you need to tag with `c#` as well as you are manuplating the crystal reports using c# code

Comment: I didn't mention , my main report work great but the sub report does not filled with data

Comment: I don't have expertise in C#.. I can't answer your question and coming to tagging.. edit your question and add C# tag to the side of the Crystal reports.